# ERROR java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number while running a Prepared Statement to alter a Sequence

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, ora-01722

```
sqlStmt = new StringBuffer("  ALTER SEQUENCE "  );  
                    sqlStmt.append( ServerContext.getSchemaName() );
                    sqlStmt.append("SEQ_EDCD_TRACE_NUM");
                    sqlStmt.append( " INCREMENT BY " );
                    sqlStmt.append( " ? " );
pstmt.setLong(1, incval);
pstmt.execute();
```

Comment: what is the type of `incval` ?

Comment: I hope you understand what this SQL command will do, namely change the increment size of the sequence for each future call to NEXT_VAL (and not increase the current value once). I've seen several times that people have incorrectly used this statement and then run out of numbers within hours. Not only did this bring the application to a halt. There was no big enough number range left either (without a number already in use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use bind variables with DDL, such as `ALTER SEQUENCE`.  You'll have to concatenate `incval` onto the string.

There shouldn't be any risk of SQL injection if `incval` is an `int` or a `long`.

Comment: thnx a ton Luke.. it worked by concatenateing incval onto the string.